# AngularJs - service does not update controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement this simple [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cTqJImTLdDwPzGsKxN6W?p=preview) with no success.
I have a simple **service (factory)** :

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.core')
    .factory('PropertiesService', PropertiesService);

function PropertiesService() {
    var sefl = this;
    self.name = 'Properties Service'
    self.properties = {};
    self.setProperties = function (prop)
    {
        self.properties = prop;
    }

    return self;
}
})();
```

I am calling this service from a **directive** :

```
var prop = { 'top': top, 'left': left, 'position': position };
service.setProperties(prop);
```

The **contoller** being updated is :

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.properties')
    .controller('Properties', Properties);

Properties.$inject = ['PropertiesService'];

function Properties(PropertiesService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.collection = {};
    setCollection();

    function setCollection() {
        for (var key in PropertiesService.properties) {
            if (PropertiesService.properties.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                vm.collection[key] = PropertiesService.properties[key];
            }
        }
    };
}
})();
```

Lastly , I am showing the data in html like this :

```
<div ng-controller="Properties as vm">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(key, value)  in vm.collection">
        <span>{{key}}</span> : <span>{{value}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I understand why i'm getting result only on initialization but I can not find the way to solve it,to make the **controller** updated when the **service** is changed (and it does) .
Thanks

Comment: `var sefl = this;` has to be `self` :)

Comment: Typo it is but it does not solve the issue. Thanks any way for pointing it out.

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: Nope. Everything is clean. My believe is, it got to do with the way i'm calling the service in the controller. I just don't understand how to make it update after the first time.

Comment: What should happen on update, what behaviour you expect?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to achieve: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ueg20OgfLBVVOj21kz0D?p=preview
In this example the value inside the service get's changed and the reference in the controller updates as expected. Or should the property name attached to MainCtrl2 should change if the value in the service changes?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you put up a plunker of your code rather than just pointing us to someone else's plunker.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note something.

In your plunker you use a `service`  and you try the same code with a `factory`. This cannot work. there are some differences between the two providers.

Either you use a `factory`:

```
function PropertiesFactory() {
    // facory doens't get invoked with the new keyword
    // so there is no this
    var self = {};
    self.name = 'Properties Factory'
    self.properties = {};
    self.setProperties = function (prop)
    {
        self.properties = prop;
    }

    return self;
}
```

or a `service`:

```
function PropertiesService() {
    var sefl = this;
    self.name = 'Properties Service'
    self.properties = {};
    self.setProperties = function (prop)
    {
        self.properties = prop;
    }
    // there is no need for return
    // since th service gets invoked with the new keyword 

}
```

form the angularjs docs about [providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers):

> The Service recipe produces a service just like the Value or Factory
>   recipes, but it does so by invoking a constructor with the new
>   operator. The constructor can take zero or more arguments, which
>   represent dependencies needed by the instance of this type.

Comment: I am using a factory.

Comment: then `var self={};` and you have to return `self`

Comment: This is not an answer to presented problem, AT MOST it is a comment about code style

Comment: ok i have updated my answer, thanks for pointing out.the difference isn't the code style btw.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/pt2xwlYqvY3r840tHJ92?p=preview the service and  factory are just simpletons it's the usage that's differs but what he want to achieve would work with service too

Comment: ok @maurycy this illustrates what I' saying http://plnkr.co/edit/8OPdMpQ8CZYv9A7fG1lY?p=preview .

Comment: Cool, that's nice one

Answer (score 0):

As it turn out i was hiding an important part of the code , not deliberately but from lack of understanding.

My **directive** is listening on **DOM events** and acting upon their changed data.
After reading this [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) (and help from my CTO...) I understood i needed to manually call **$scope.$apply()**.

Now I have an element i can resize,drag etc. and have its changed properties eflect on the screen.

Now the binding is working again I can revert the controller code to look like this:

```
function Properties(PropertiesService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.collection = PropertiesService.data;
}
```

Everything is in sync.

Sorry for the partial data , and thanks for the help.

Gilad